# Pure CSS automatic fade out not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a transition that works as I expect on chrome, but it does not work at all on Firefox.

To be honest, I think I'm missunderstanding something and that it works on chrome because some kind of bug or non expected behavior.

This is the CSS rule (based on bootstrap 3 alert class):

```
.alert {
  transition: opacity 1s ease 5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease 5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease 5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

What I expect is, when the page loads, the alert is visible, and after the specified timeout it fades out, which is exactly what happens on chorme. But on firefox it appears directly with an opacity of 0, which is the opposite of what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're going to need more context. A working example would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something to transition *to*. At the moment your initial state (based on the code you've shared) is `opacity:0;`. You want the element to have `opacity:1;` when it loads, and then transition *to* `opacity:0;`.

You could do this by adding a class with JS after 5 seconds, and that new class has `opacity:0`, but then you're not using pure CSS.

Perhaps a better option would be to use a CSS animation. You'd have to change the way you're approaching the problem, though. The regular CSS load-state would be `opacity:0;` but you'd use an animation to change the opacity to `1` when it loads, then wait 5-seconds, and fade the opacity to `0`. The whole animation would last 6 seconds, and if you were using percentages to set the timing of your animation, you'd want to start the fade-out at 83.33% (5/6 of the total duration).

```
.alert {
  -webkit-animation:fadeout 6s linear;
          animation:fadeout 6s linear;
  opacity:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout{
  0%{opacity:1;}
  83.33%{opacity:1;}
  100%{opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout{
  0%{opacity:1;}
  83.33%{opacity:1;}
  100%{opacity:0;}
}
```

Comment: I though about using animations too, but I wanted the solution to be as simple as possible. Since my very simple solution was working on chrome, I wanted to test it out on firefox, and the behavior is (surprise!) the opposite. As you said, my default state should be `opacity:0`, which seems correct, but the fact that it works as expected on chrome confuses me. Maybe chrome applies first the defualt and then performs the animation. While this is fine for my purpose, I think it is not the correct behavior